# Camel CXF Component: Call ws with Json String body

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I could not get along with the Camel CXF component. The problem is, th WS operation that I want to call has only a String parameter which is a JSON expression.

But , with every dataFormat (MESSAGE,POJO,PAYLOAD), it gives exception.

There are classes which are generated from wsdl2java by cxf itself and I am using them to call ws.

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="wsEndpoint" address="http://www.wssss.com" serviceClass="aa.bb.cc.WebService" serviceName="sendMessage">
    <cxf:properties>
         <entry key="dataFormat" value="CXF_MESSAGE"/>
        <entry key="defaultOperationName" value="sendMessage"/>
        <entry key="relayHeaders" value="false"/>
        <entry key="wrapped" value="true"/>
        <entry key="loggingFeatureEnabled" value="true"/>
        <entry key="synchronous" value="true"/>
        <entry key="defaultOperationNamespace" value="http://com.asdad.ns"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

and I am using this in:

```
camel:to uri="cxf:bean:wsEndpoint"/>
```

And generated service class is:

```
@WebResult(name = "response", targetNamespace = "")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "sendMessage", targetNamespace = "http://com.xxx.comet.ws.notification", className = "aaa.bbb.ccc.SendMessage")
@WebMethod
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "sendMessageResponse", targetNamespace = "http://com.xxx.comet.ws.notification", className = "aaa.bbb.ccc.SendMessageResponse")
public java.lang.String sendMessage(
    @WebParam(name = "request", targetNamespace = "")
    java.lang.String request
);
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

EDIT: The problem is, exchange.in body could not be bound with the service method's parameter so request is empty. There is the problem in here

```
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 1
Address: http://www.wssss.com
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], breadcrumbId=[ID-TT08328507-61662-1416561287466-0-1], SOAPAction=[""]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/><soap:Body/></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
Nov 21, 2014 4:45:04 AM org.apache.cxf.services.sendMessage.MessagePort.Message
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {connection=[close], Content-Length=[271], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], Date=[Fri, 21 Nov 2014 09:15:04 GMT], Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: No binding operation info while invoking unknown method with params unknown.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
```

Comment: You say that you get an exception. What is the exception? Please also provide the route.

Comment: @Ray I have edited...

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The outbind message is an empty SOAP envelop.

```
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/><soap:Body/></soap:Envelope>
```

Did setup the invocation parameter rightly?